# Angular-fullstack get current user ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm using https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack.

I have 2 schemas:

- charts

  - title: String
  - datasets: Array
  - _creator: logged in user ID
- users

  - name
  - email
  - _id

When I console.log the current user returns
[image]

```
$scope.getCurrentUser = Auth.getCurrentUser();        
console.log($scope.getCurrentUser);
```

But when I try to console log the _id:

```
$scope.getCurrentUser = Auth.getCurrentUser();        
console.log($scope.getCurrentUser._id);
```

Returns

> undefined

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you should start with an Angular tutorial and read up on asynchronous execution of JavaScript. Google for "angular promise". Basically, the request hasn't resolved yet, you'll have to wait for it to be loaded...

Comment: Then why when I console.log it returns the entire object but ._id its undefined?

Comment: i don't know angular-fullstack, but `Auth.getCurrentUser()` returns a promise, not your `currentUser`. you need something like the following: `Auth.getCurrentUser().then(function(result){// do something with result; result should be your currentUser});`

Comment: @Marius: the console is a *watcher* when you pass a reference, whereas `._id` is evaluated immediately

Comment: In addition to this problem, `isLoggedIn` doesn't update properly either. Some frontend elements rely on it with ng-show/hide. After login, the function still returns false, until I refresh the page. Any clue?

Comment: And I think it is not correct that the function necessarily returns a promise (which would be a logical answer to this problem of course). The implementation looks like it's working synchronously, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects in chrome console get evaluated only when they are first opened.

This means that when you console.log an object like the return value of `Auth.getCurrentUser()`, the console displays a reference to it - this at the time of the log call contains a promise object, but it's most likely resolved by the time you open it on the console, so you see the property you're looking for.

On the other hand, when you're logging `$scope.getCurrentUser._id`, that's the result of a property lookup on the promise object - and it prints the current value of the property, which is `undefined`.

*A note about clean code: your scope variable is called getCurrentUser, which makes one think it's a getter function, but it is infact the return value of a getter function. This is confusing.*

Comment: If you look into the implementation of `getCurrentUser` you will find that it can work synchronously as well as asynchronously. If you do not provide parameters (like a callback function), it should respond synchronously. This is unfortunately not the case. Am I missing something?

Comment: @molerat I see where you're coming from, but you can see in OP's screenshot that a Promise object was returned to him. Your reasoning seems correct, but maybe the implementation was different back then? (It's been 1.5 years...) Either way, you seem to point out a slightly unrelated issue with your latest comments to OP, I recommend opening a new question instead.